# Replace values in email with values coming from List

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an email template

For example this

> Hello @FirstName@ @LastName@

I have an object that comes from a parameter with properties

I need to iterate all object properties and replace all words that matched the property name quoted with @@ with property value.

So, for example, I have an object with FirstName and LastName, I need to iterate this object property and change @FirstName@ and @LastName@ in email.

The style of object was like this

```
{'FirstName': 'Eugene', 'LastName': 'Sukhomlyn'}
```

And code for this was like this

```
return Regex.Replace(template, @"@(?<prop>\w+)@", m =>
    {
        var property = input.GetType().GetProperty(m.Groups["prop"].Value);

        if (property != null)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(input);
            if (value != null)
                return value.ToString();
        }

        return "";
    });
```

But I changed model to this, so now it List of objects

```
[{'Key': 'FirstName', 'Value': 'Eugene'},{'Key': 'LastName', 'Value': 'Sukhomlyn'}]
```

So logic will be like this, I need to get Key value and find text to replace @FirstName@ in this example and replace it with Value.

How I can do this?

Comment: Why you minus question?

Answer (score 0):

So I can do it like this

```
foreach (var item in input)
{
    var key = item.GetType().GetProperty("Key")?.GetValue(item, null)?.ToString();
    var value = item.GetType().GetProperty("Value")?.GetValue(item, null)?.ToString();
    template = template.Replace($"@{key}@", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your list into a `Dictionary<string, string>` and then replace your code by

```
return Regex.Replace(template, @"@(?<prop>\w+)@", 
    m => dict.TryGetValue(m.Groups["prop"].Value, out var value) ? value : "");
```